# How to check if a combined value of two columns exist in another dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple dfs with two common columns

Sample df

```
user_id and event_date
abc   |  1st june
abc   |  2nd June
cdf   | 15th july
dfg   | 17th July
```

I want to check if a `user_id` on a particular `event_date` in df1 also exists in df2, df3, df4, and df5

How do I find this ?

the following methods I tried but it worked with only taking "`user_id`" into consideration and not with "`event_date`"

method 1:

```
upi_sms =df1.assign(Insms=df2.user_id.isin(df1.user_id).astype(int))
```

method 2:
merging dataframes `on = [user_id, event_date]`

none of it gives me expected results.

Expected Result:

```
Combination of abc and 1st June should exist in df2
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way, consider simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':['A','B','C'],'y':[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':['C','A','B'],'y':[3,2,1]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'x':['A','B','C'],'y':[0,0,0]})
```

and say you are interested in last row of `df1`, i.e. where x is C and y is 3. Such row is also present in `df2` (1st) but not `df3` where there is row with x being C but have different.

```
row = tuple(df1.iloc[-1]) # get last row of df1 as tuple
print(row in df2.itertuples(index=False)) # True
print(row in df3.itertuples(index=False)) # False
```

Observe it is important to pass `index=False` as we did not want to take into account where number is inside `pandas.DataFrame`

Comment: What if I dont want just the last row , but I want to check in the whole dataframe?

Comment: @coder_bg prepare `set` based on each `pandas.DataFrame` like `set(df.itertuples(index=False))` and then get their intersection